# How can I increase the length of the warmup round?

Tags: server-administration, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am setting up a Counterstrike: Global Offensive server and I was wondering if I could increase the length of the warm up around? Currently it is about 30 seconds but I'd like to customise this yet can't find any setting that allows this.

I assume this would be something that is customised per game mode in gamemodes_server.txt but I have been unable to find anything on Google or in the documentation explaining how to change this.

Is it possible to increase the length of the warmup round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could find in the console you have to use:

```
MP_warmuptime 60
```

This would set the warmup time to 60 seconds.
The standard is at 25 seconds and the minimum is 5 seconds.

Also as a tip for next time: 
in the console you can do `find "text"`
and it will find all console commands with that text in it.

Comment: i'm assuming you know how to run and startup a server. if not i'll edit my post later cause i would have to look that up myself aswell

Comment: yeah I've got the server up and running - just trying to customise many of the settings. Thanks for the 'find' tip though, I wasn't aware of that!